# Complexity of m bit multiplication & division

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotics

In [PRIMES IS IN P](https://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/manindra/algebra/primality_v6.pdf) paper, page 6 under Time Complexity section, authors have mentioned *"In these calculations we use the fact that addition, multiplication, and division operations between two m bits numbers can be performed in time O∼(m)"*.

What is O~(m)? -I am aware of O(m) notation. How is multiplication and division *linear* in number of bits?